# Compiler error `assigning incompatible type within if statement`

Tags: c++, templates, if-statement, function-templates, template-classes

The compiler keeps assigning incompatible types during the build.

error Message:

```
error: assigning to 'int' from incompatible type 'QString'
typeduserproperty.cpp:115:28: note: in instantiation of member function 'core::TypedUserProperty<int>::setValue' requested here
```

Sample code

```
 /**
  * @brief setValue
  * set value to property
  * @param val
  * value to set to property
  * @return
  * true - successfully set value
  * false - invalid value
  */
template<class T>
void TypedUserProperty<T>::setValue(QVariant val)
{

   if (std::is_same<T, int>::value == true) 
   {
      this->_value = val.toInt();
   }
   else if (std::is_same<T, QString>::value == true)
   {
      this->_value = val.toString();
   }
   else if (std::is_same<T, double>::value == true)
   {
      this->_value = val.toDouble();
   }
}
```

`this->_value = val.toString();` is the line the error occurs

"_value" is data type template T

in this case i'm setting the T Template as an 'int'

does anyone know why this is occuring or if theres a workaround.

Comment: 'The compiler keeps assigning incompatible types'. No. The compiler keeps *printing compilation errors* about *you* assigning incompatible types.

Comment: The compiler does no such thing. You wrote that code, not the compiler :). The error tells you where the issue is *in your code*, it’s not a declaration of mea culpa on the compiler’s part. It could be argued that the language should allow such code, but you’d have to take that up with the standards committee. I agree that the behavior you observe is somewhat silly. But rules are rules, and this behavior could not be safely added to C++ without additional syntax. It would have extremely unintended consequences; it’d be downright dangerous in fact.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is, even if you specify the template argument as `int`, those `else` parts have to be instantiated at compile-time.

You can apply [Constexpr If](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_If) (since C++17).

> If the value is `true`, then statement-false is discarded (if present), otherwise, statement-true is discarded.

e.g.

```
if constexpr (std::is_same<T,int>::value == true) {
    this->_value = val.toInt();
} else if constexpr (std::is_same<T,QString>::value == true) {
    this->_value = val.toString();
} else if constexpr (std::is_same<T,double>::value == true){
    this->_value = val.toDouble();
}
```

Answer (score 6):

> Does anyone know why this is occurring or if there's a workaround?

Since you are using (normal) `if-else`, even if only one of the conditions is true, all the remaining `else` branches will be initiated at compile time.

1. ### Solution - 1

   If you have access only to [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11), SFINE(i.e.["Substitution Failure Is Not An
   Error"](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae)) technique along with function overloading will be one way to go. That will **only turn-on(i.e. instantiate)** the correct method according to the class template `T`, in `TypedUserProperty<T>` class
   instantiation.

   ```cpp
   #include <type_traits> // std::enable_if, std::is_same

   // helper traits for `std::enable_if`
   template<typename T, typename ReType = void> using EnableIfInteger = typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, int>::value, ReType>::type;
   template<typename T, typename ReType = void> using EnableIfDouble = typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, double>::value, ReType>::type;
   template<typename T, typename ReType = void> using EnableIfQString = typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, QString>::value, ReType>::type;

   template<class T> class TypedUserProperty
   {
      T _value;
   public:
      template<typename Type = T> // this will be instantiated when T = int
      auto setValue(QVariant val)->EnableIfInteger<Type> {
          this->_value = val.toInt();
      }

      template<typename Type = T> // this will be instantiated when T = double
      auto setValue(QVariant val)->EnableIfDouble<Type> {
          this->_value = val.toDouble();
      }

      template<typename Type = T> // this will be instantiated when T = QString
      auto setValue(QVariant val)->EnableIfQString<Type> {
          this->_value = val.toString();
      }
   };
   ```
2. ### Solution - 2

   The above solution is more verbose, in [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17), as it provides
   the [`if constexpr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if)
   feature. With this, one can **instantiate the only branch** which is
   true at compile time.
   [@songyuanyao](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58576826/c-compiler-error-assigning-incompatible-type-within-if-statement/58576847#58576847)
   has explained this in his answer btw.